# How to loop this statement with 3 changing values to setText for 40 textfields?

Tags: java, loops

Here is the code when I haven't stored in a list. This gets what I want to display in different textfields but I want it to be shorter so I want to loop it.

//"answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(i,TB)" is a function from other class that returns an arraylist;

```
quizAnswer1store.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(0));
            quizAnswer2store.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(1));
            quizAnswer3store.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(2));
            quizAnswer4store.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(3));
            quizAnswer1store2.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(0));
            quizAnswer2store2.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(1));
            quizAnswer3store2.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(2));
            quizAnswer4store2.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(3));
            quizAnswer1store3.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(0));
            quizAnswer2store3.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(1));
            quizAnswer3store3.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(2));
            quizAnswer4store3.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(3));
```

I stored it in a List "quizAnswerSTORE" and I tried to loop but doesnt work.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<quizAnswerSTORE.size(); i++){
       for(int j = 1; j < 11; j++){
           while(k<4){
              quizAnswerSTORE.get(i).setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(j,TB).get(k));
       }
    }
}
```

The expected result is to diplay different values from a database in different 40 txtfields. Because each time the loop values increments, it rolls through my database with different values. J variable represents the id in my database. And the K is an index in the values taken in the arrayList returned by retrieveDataAnswers function from a four columned database.

There you go. I hope you can solve this.

Comment: This is very unclear. Post your code and explain what is the difference between the expected and actual results.

Comment: Please paste full expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod to control maximun int values, for example `i % 10` can't take values more than 10.

### Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j = 1;
        int k = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

            System.out.println("quizAnswerSTORE"+i+".setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices("+j+",TB).get("+k+"));");
            k = (k + 1)%4;

            if( k == 0) {
                j = (j+1) % 11;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

### output:

```
quizAnswerSTORE0.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(0));
quizAnswerSTORE1.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(1));
quizAnswerSTORE2.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(2));
quizAnswerSTORE3.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(1,TB).get(3));
quizAnswerSTORE4.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(0));
quizAnswerSTORE5.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(1));
quizAnswerSTORE6.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(2));
quizAnswerSTORE7.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(2,TB).get(3));
quizAnswerSTORE8.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(0));
quizAnswerSTORE9.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(1));
quizAnswerSTORE10.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(2));
quizAnswerSTORE11.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(3,TB).get(3));
...
quizAnswerSTORE38.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(10,TB).get(2));
quizAnswerSTORE39.setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(10,TB).get(3));
```

Comment: You're a genius bro! The only thing i've done is to add a clear () method when k ==0 . Thanks bro. Hpw did you dp that?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to be consistent with your indentation and line up closing brackets '}' with their corresponding statement.

The first problem I see with this code is that k is never incremented inside the while loop so it will always have the same value and loop forever. The second problem I see is that k is not reset after the while loop so when it goes through the loop the first time (and is correctly incremented) it will stay at a value of 4 and the loop will be skipped every time after that.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve (I could use some more information or a sample output) but to begin with you can correct the loop error by changing the while loop to a for loop like so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < quizAnswerSTORE.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            quizAnswerSTORE.get(i).setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(j,TB).get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the while loop, you could so it like so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < quizAnswerSTORE.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        int k = 0; // Set k inside the 2nd loop and it will reset to 0 after the while loop
        while(k < 4) {
            quizAnswerSTORE.get(i).setText(answerStoration.retrieveDataChoices(j,TB).get(k));
            k++; // Shorthand for k += 1 which is shorthand for k = k + 1
        }
    }
}
```